# How to sequentially run multiple script in python

Tags: python

I have a list of .py file that I need to run sequentially.
I usually do it manually, one by one.

Anyway I'd like to have a .py file by which I run these .py automatically.

In R I usually use the command `source`:

```
Source (file1, file2 etc)
```

Is there a way to do anything similar in python?
By the way, I use IDLE, so I'd like to have a solution using this program.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could try `import file1, file2`. That will import all the modules, which means running them. However, they won't be the `__main__` module. So anything inside a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block won't be run. Each file will also run in its own namespace. I suspect `Source` runs all those files in the same namespace.

Comment: IDLE should not be relevant, anymore than any other IDE.  Your code is executed by python, not the IDE feeding your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
execfile(filename)
```

is probably what you want to use

for instance if you have a list of files to run
e.g.

```
files_to_run = ["path_to/File1", "path_to/File2", "path_to/File3", "path_to/File4"]

for file in files_to_run:
    execfile(file)
```

Comment: Since `execfile` is no longer supported in Python 3, this will only temporarily help, if at all.

Comment: hmm ill try and find the code where i did this, it was a long time ago but i managed to restart the file using a function

Comment: okay found out a better thing to do if you import all the files into your code then have them all have a common function (like c++  int main() ) then after all of the files are imported you could call the functions in the order you like this hould also allwo you to check for return values

Comment: Thank you. I try your code but I got this error: NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined.

Comment: ye turns out execfile was removed in python 3.8 you wou;ld do what i commented above

Answer (score 0):

simple `import` technically executes the file.

In python, it is common practice to use to define all the required functions int he module and function calls are defined inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` [means the code inside the if will execute only if the script called directly not when imported]

so that the same module can used as executable and also imported in another file.

Technically, if you did not use `if __name__ == "__main__":` in your files, simply import itself will execute them.